# User table design seperating password related columns

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm designing an application and I need to create an user registration system. I have the following table structure

[image]

Where it doesn't click for me is that should I separate all password related columns onto another table as PASSWORD and connect this to main user table with a foreign key. Having said that, currently passwords are derived with a key derivation algorithm meaning two passwords wouldn't yield the same output digest. However, I wonder if having the user table like this or with a foreign key connecting to the password related columns would increase the performance by any means?

Comment: Keep it in the same table.

Comment: can you define on that more possibly :) ?

Comment: Have you observed performance is poor and what performance are you aiming for?

Comment: I've just started to implement the thing. I dont wanna make tremendous changes on the way with the table structures. Instead of doing what I assume to be true, wanted to ask to experts of it, in the first place.

Comment: I'll have to add other foreigner key columns to this table along the way, so was thinking 12 columns in the start is already a bit too much?! Or is it all normal? I'm quite beginner in DB designs, so any insight is appreciated

Comment: 'MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective maximum may be less for a given table.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html - there's a smell of premature optimisation here.

Comment: Are you concerned about security, or what?  Do you need to keep (or be able to recreate) the password(s)?  Or just check them after using a salt and one-way hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an interest in historical passwords.  That suggests that you have the wrong data model.  It sounds like you want a type-2 table -- one that keeps track of passwords over time:

```
create table user_passwords (
    user_password_id int auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int not null,
    password varchar(100),
    eff_date datetime not null,
    end_date datetime,
    constraint fk_user_passwords_user_id (user_id) references users(user_id)
);
```

When a user changes the password, you would then insert a new row into this table, adjusting the `eff_date` and `end_date`s.

Note:  The purpose of doing this is not for performance.  The purpose is to accurately represent the data that you seem to need for your application.

This doesn't include the "trials".  I'm not sure what that really means and it probably doesn't need to be kept historically, so that can stay in the `users` table.